Effective mass tensor
The (Inverse) effective mass tensor values at conduction band minimum i.e. for electrons and valence band maximum i.e. for holes are expected to be positive and negative respectively. The computed diagonal component values in my computations are following this. However, some (not all) off-diagonal components (xy, yz and zx) are not following this i.e. negative values for electrons and positive values for holes. What can be the possible reasons for this?

There's no requirement for particular elements of the effective mass tensor to be positive (or negative), only the eigenvalues are important.

Thanks @PhilHasnip for the helpful comment. Can you please also tell which effective mass value is more appropriate to use to compute electrical conductivity by formula ne^2/m*- Conductivity m*, Density of states m* or any other?

@AbPhys please stick to one question per post.
